# Merge Separate Windows (and tabs within) into one in Sublime Text 3

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3

On my mac, I work with a lot of tabs and windows in SublimeText 3. I often like to pull tabs out to create a new window but later, I want to be able to easily consolidate them.

Scenario: I have two SublimeText windows open, each with 5 tabs. Now, I'd like to merge all the tabs of window 2 into window 1 so I only have one remaining window with 10 tabs.

Chrome has a fabulous extension called [Merge Windows](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-windows/mmpokgfcmbkfdeibafoafkiijdbfblfg?hl=en/) that demonstrates this behavior perfectly.

How would I do this in SublimeText 3?

Comment: Great question. Similarly, when I launch ST3 from command line with the common `subl` alias, I want all new files launched in same window, just separate tabs.

Comment: If you can drag the tabs out to make new windows, can't you just drag the tabs back into the other window?

Comment: @RoweMorehouse Add this `"open_files_in_new_window": false` to `Settings - User`. This will open all files to the same window but their respective tabs.

Comment: @Row Morehouse: I don't want all docs to open in same window as I have many reasons for using different windows. I just want to be able to quickly (preferably by keyboard) consolidate everything.

Comment: @Blkc, one can do this but when you have 25+ tabs it's quickly apparent a keyboard shortcut or one-click solution is necessary.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to try using multiple focus groups instead of multiple windows. It's much easier to consolidate everything by simply going back to a single focus group, which would contain all the tabs of both. Of course this hinges on having enough screen real estate.

Comment: I would be happen if I can merge tabs by drag and drop them into the parent window - the current setup only allow merge when drag and drop a tab into the tab area on a window - which is very small and often hide behind other windows. It would also be cool if the whole window becomes invisible when dragging a tab.

Comment: I'm looking for the solution too. Finder has a menu item in menu > Window > Merge all windows. Therefore, I'd like one if Sublime Text supports.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have created a sublime package to help solve this problem called [Merge Windows](https://github.com/chinchin96/SublimeText-Merge-Windows).

It can be downloaded from  [github](https://github.com/chinchin96/SublimeText-Merge-Windows)  or through Sublime using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Merge%20Windows)

Answer (score 8):

[Not sure for other OS but for MAC it is easy and very useful]

In mac, open sublime,

```
click Window -> Click Merge all Windows
```

Also make sure that this won't work if you just have one window open which is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't exactly what you're asking for but I think this is close enough:

Drag the tab from the "source" window to the "target" Window and hover near the other tabs in the source window. Then drop it there. Voila. You've moved one tab.
Rinse and repeat for the other tabs.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but not supported and could potentially blow away your buffers if you mess up. So backup this file.

/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session

This file contains all of your session data, all windows, tabs search history, etc.

You can move an entire window of tabs from one window to another with the following instructions:

Look for the "Windows" JSON entry, inside of that is a list of windows, the list is indicated with the [] brackets and is comma separated. Inside of each 'Window' entry in the 'Windows' list is a "Buffers" list, each 'Buffer' represents a Tab. 
There is also a "groups" list that contains a "sheets" list which functions identically but contains information about the tabs and not so much the content.

There are other bits of data in there that we are not interested in for this exercise, but it is very important that the file passes JSON validation before you open Sublime.

```
"windows":
[
    {
        "auto_complete":
        {
            "selected_items":
            [
            ]
        },
        "buffers":
        [
            {
                "contents": "This tab has not been saved and is in Window 1",
                "settings":
                {
                    "buffer_size": 46,
                    "line_ending": "Unix",
                    "name": "This tab has not been saved and is in Window 1"
                }
            },
            {
                "file": "/Users/username/Desktop/This file has been saved and not changed and is in Window 1",
                "settings":
                {
                    "buffer_size": 59,
                    "line_ending": "Unix",
                    "name": "This file has been saved and not changed and is in Window 1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "groups":
        [
            {
                "selected": 0,
                "sheets":
                [
                    {
                        "buffer": 0,
                        "semi_transient": false,
                        "settings":
                        {
                            "buffer_size": 46,
                            "regions":
                            {
                            },
                            "selection":
                            [
                                [
                                    46,
                                    46
                                ]
                            ],
                            "settings":
                            {
                                "auto_name": "This tab has not been saved and is in Window 1",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
                            },
                            "translation.x": 0.0,
                            "translation.y": 0.0,
                            "zoom_level": 1.0
                        },
                        "stack_index": 0,
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "buffer": 1,
                        "file": "/Users/username/Desktop/This file has been saved and not changed and is in Window 1",
                        "semi_transient": false,
                        "settings":
                        {
                            "buffer_size": 59,
                            "regions":
                            {
                            },
                            "selection":
                            [
                                [
                                    59,
                                    59
                                ]
                            ],
                            "settings":
                            {
                                "auto_name": "This file has been saved and not changed and is in",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
                            },
                            "translation.x": 0.0,
                            "translation.y": 0.0,
                            "zoom_level": 1.0
                        },
                        "stack_index": 1,
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "buffers":
        [
            {
                "contents": "This tab is also unsaved and in Window 2.",
                "settings":
                {
                    "buffer_size": 41,
                    "line_ending": "Unix",
                    "name": "This tab is also unsaved and in Window 2."
                }
            }
        ],
        "groups":
        [
            {
                "selected": 0,
                "sheets":
                [
                    {
                        "buffer": 0,
                        "semi_transient": false,
                        "settings":
                        {
                            "buffer_size": 41,
                            "regions":
                            {
                            },
                            "selection":
                            [
                                [
                                    41,
                                    41
                                ]
                            ],
                            "settings":
                            {
                                "auto_name": "This tab is also unsaved and in Window 2.",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
                            },
                            "translation.x": 0.0,
                            "translation.y": 0.0,
                            "zoom_level": 1.0
                        },
                        "stack_index": 0,
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

If you relocate each 'buffer' entry from the second 'window' to the end of the first, and repeat for each 'sheet' under 'groups'. Then update the 'buffer' number to be higher for each of the sheet entries, they should be sequential following the entry that was previously there. When you open Sublime 3 you will notice all your tabs from Window 2 are now in Window 1.

The edited session file will look kinda like this:

```
    "windows":
[
    {
        "auto_complete":
        {
            "selected_items":
            [
            ]
        },
        "buffers":
        [
            {
                "contents": "This tab has not been saved and is in Window 1",
                "settings":
                {
                    "buffer_size": 46,
                    "line_ending": "Unix",
                    "name": "This tab has not been saved and is in Window 1"
                }
            },
            {
                "file": "/Users/username/Desktop/This file has been saved and not changed and is in",
                "settings":
                {
                    "buffer_size": 59,
                    "line_ending": "Unix",
                    "name": "This file has been saved and not changed and is in"
                },

            },
            {
                "contents": "This tab is also unsaved and in Window 2.",
                "settings":
                {
                    "buffer_size": 41,
                    "line_ending": "Unix",
                    "name": "This tab is also unsaved and in Window 2."
                }
            }
        ],
        "groups":
        [
            {
                "selected": 0,
                "sheets":
                [
                    {
                        "buffer": 0,
                        "semi_transient": false,
                        "settings":
                        {
                            "buffer_size": 46,
                            "regions":
                            {
                            },
                            "selection":
                            [
                                [
                                    46,
                                    46
                                ]
                            ],
                            "settings":
                            {
                                "auto_name": "This tab has not been saved and is in Window 1",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
                            },
                            "translation.x": 0.0,
                            "translation.y": 0.0,
                            "zoom_level": 1.0
                        },
                        "stack_index": 0,
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "buffer": 1,
                        "file": "/Users/username/Desktop/This file has been saved and not changed and is in",
                        "semi_transient": false,
                        "settings":
                        {
                            "buffer_size": 59,
                            "regions":
                            {
                            },
                            "selection":
                            [
                                [
                                    59,
                                    59
                                ]
                            ],
                            "settings":
                            {
                                "auto_name": "This file has been saved and not changed and is in",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
                            },
                            "translation.x": 0.0,
                            "translation.y": 0.0,
                            "zoom_level": 1.0
                        },
                        "stack_index": 1,
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "buffer": 2,
                        "semi_transient": false,
                        "settings":
                        {
                            "buffer_size": 41,
                            "regions":
                            {
                            },
                            "selection":
                            [
                                [
                                    41,
                                    41
                                ]
                            ],
                            "settings":
                            {
                                "auto_name": "This tab is also unsaved and in Window 2.",
                                "syntax": "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage"
                            },
                            "translation.x": 0.0,
                            "translation.y": 0.0,
                            "zoom_level": 1.0
                        },
                        "stack_index": 0,
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "buffers":
        [
        ],
        "groups":
        [
            {
                "selected": 0,
                "sheets":
                [
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

There you have it. It's not pretty or direct, but it will get the job done and could be scripted using Python, Perl, or a number of other languages pretty quickly especially if you used a JSON library.

Comment: Hey Joshua, thanks for this idea. What do you mean by "Not supported"? As in SublimeText has no provisions to this, even through a package? Ideally, I'd love to have a package (e.g. on packagecontrol.io) as I feel a lot of people would benefit from a polished implementation. I'm no programmer though...

Comment: That's correct. There is no feature to perform a merge of two buffer files automatically within Sublime, and but it is possible to do it yourself since the file since is JSON. Sublime could add a buffer merge feature, but that will depend if the author finds the idea useful enough to justify the implementing it. Another feature that could be useful would be Cloud Sync of the buffers between machines. Maybe also adding exporting/importing of windows or tab buffer groups to file.